# How Backbone.js event handling works and customization

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I am modifying the site called [Amigos](https://amigos.social/)!. It is a mental health social platform for young adults to discuss general life problems. I am having trouble with Backbone.js. The theme comes with a vote button on a question page. The HTML code for the in `single-question` page is:

```
<div id="question_content" class="row question-main-content question-item"></div>
<!-- END QUESTION-MAIN-CONTENT -->
<div class="row question-main-content question-item answer-item"></div>
<!-- END ANSWER-CONTENT -->
```

and each question container and answer contain has a button

```
<a class="action vote vote-up img-circle"></a>
```

The js for capturing the click action is defined as

```
Views.PostListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'row question-main-content question-item answer-item',
        model: [],
        events: {
                'click a.action': 'doAction',
        }
        doAction: function(event) {
                # mycode
        }
});
```

I notice that the className includes `answer-item`. When I clicked the button in the *question container*, it executes the code the stops at the line where I placed a debugger. I wonder why this works? Shouldn't only the buttons in the answer container be executed because their `class` attributes exactly match `className` in `js`.

Also, I am trying to add a vote button on the other page. Do I just simply copy the `js` code and change the `classname` attribute to that of my container in new page?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know how event handlers in Backbone's views work?

Comment: Yes. That my question :)